# CakePHP limit of mysql is 20 without me setting it. How do i remove this limit?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, limit

I have a mysql call with pagination that looks like that:

```
$this->paginate['limit'] = 400;
$this->paginate['Word']= array('contain'=>"");
$wording = $this->paginate('Word');
```

and the result is:

```
SELECT `Word`.`id`, `Word`.`special`, FROM `words` AS `Word` WHERE `Word`.`writing_translation_id` = 197 LIMIT 20
```

So this limit of 20 appears from somewhere and I can't find where. I checked the controller and the model and couldn't find anything such. As you see also, i couldn't overwrite it with a specific limit set to 400;

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $this->paginate['Word] = array('contain' => '', 'limit' => 400);

Comment: thanx, that worked. Do you know where the default 20 could come from?

Comment: @mgPePe: I think the default might be defined in the `PaginatorComponent` definition.  See for example here: http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/cakephp/cakephp-cakephp-ec45e4e/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php

Comment: It is the default and it happened because you passed the wrong options. So it did not get it because you had to move your limit to the model specific array.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answer is correct, it is very limited in scope. What happens when the return value is beyond 400? Set the value to 999999999? This is bad programming practice. We're using machines that can execute queries, manipulate data and perform calculations in nano-seconds. Thus, we should be exercising extreme precision where possible. This is definitely one of those cases.

A very very simple solution to this problem is to run a quick find->('count') with the same conditions as the paginate query if a request for "view all" has been made (presumably passed via a $_GET parameter), and set the limit to this value.

Comment: Could you maybe explain this in more detail? I found this question while searching for a "view all" option for paginate but I don't understand how to actually implement the request part for what you said in CakePHP 3.x.

Comment: You shouldn't use the paginator for view all or no limit queries. I mean realistically you shouldn't use list all queries period. But I digress. Sounds like you need the "list" query.